# Role Based Access Control on parts of objects

Tags: access-control, role-based-access-control

I tried to understand RBAC in order to determine if it is a good solution for our problem.

Let say that the context is a bank. Among the several actors, we have account managers and clients.

I think I have understand RBAC for the account manager. If we imagine Account Managers can create, modify, view and remove accounts, then:

- `Account Manager` is a *role*,
- `create`, `modify`, `view`, `remove` are the *operations*,
- `accounts` are *objects*
- `create account` is one of the *permissions* associated to the *role* `Account Manager`

But my problem is about clients ... They can consult only **their** accounts.

My problem is: How can we specified this particular account in RBAC? Is it at least possible or must I choose another way of manage access control? And which of them?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RBAC - How to implement per instance access control? (DDD)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33515483/rbac-how-to-implement-per-instance-access-control-ddd)

Comment: Use attribute based access control and xacml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentionned, Attribute based access control may be the good solution. And XACML could be used in an application with complex policies.

Here is a very understandable documentation about [ABAC in Spring Security](https://dzone.com/articles/simple-attribute-based-access-control-with-spring)